# VBA Copy Email as .MSG to New Email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am new to using VBA and I've looked around trying to find a solution. I don't know if this is even possible but I'm going to try and see if anyone can come up with any ideas.

So when you go into Outlook and you right click on an email, you can select copy. When you create a new email and paste the email, the copied email gets attached as a .msg as an attached file.

I am trying to replicate this process. Right now my process is

1. Find email

   ```
   InStr(olMail.Subject, "SUBJECT") <> 0
   ```
2. Display email

   ```
   olMail.Display
   ```
3. Copy body and set text to strPaste

   ```
   Buf.SetText(OlMail.Body)
   Buf.PutInClipBoard 
   strPaste = Buf.GetText(1)
   ```
4. Create new email

   ```
   MailItem = OlApp.CreateItem(0)
   ```
5. Paste body

   ```
   .Body = strPaste
   ```

This works but it isn't as clean because there are other things that are going into a message and it would be better for the copied email to be attached to an email instead of copying the body text.

I also don't want to save the email as an .msg and then attach it because other people will be using the macro and it would be quite tedious to change the path of where the email gets saved for every individual.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: This looks like an *x,y problem* to me... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I can definitely see why that is the case. I only provided my first "attempted" solution for anyone that wanted to just copy and paste the email into their body. I know I will have to complete redo my code but I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when you go into Outlook and you right click on an email, you can select copy. When you create a new email and paste the email, the copied email gets attached as a .msg as an attached file.
>
> I am trying to replicate this process.

*When forwarding MailItem as Attachment, use [olEmbeddeditem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868693.aspx)
Which the Outlook message format file (.msg) is a copy of the original message to the new message.*

Example in vba would be

```
Option Explicit
Sub Example()
    '//  Declare variables
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    
    ' Select Item
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No Item selected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Set Msg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With Msg
            .Attachments.Add Item, olEmbeddeditem ' Attch Selected email
            .Display
        End With
    Next
    
    '// Clean up
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Select the Email that you would like to copy as .msg to new Email, then run the code*

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Om3r Is it possible to attach multiple searched emails as an attachment using the method you provided?

Comment: @Joshua, just move this line `Set Msg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)` outside `For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` loop, -   [ it Creates the mail item, then loop thru selected items while attaching to it. :-) ]